# Explicit representation of weights for Newton-Cotes

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

For the [*closed* Newton-Cotes quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cotes_formulas#Closed_Newton.E2.80.93Cotes_formulae) over $[x_1, x_n]$, the coefficients $H_{n,i}$ for
$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_n} f(x)\:\text{d}x = h \sum_{i=1}^n H_{n,i} \; f(x_i)
$$
are given explicitly by
$$
H_{n,r+1} =\frac{(-1)^{n-r}}{r!(n-r)!}\int_0^n \frac{\prod_{k=0}^n (t-k)}{t-r}\:\text{d}t;
$$
see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Newton-CotesFormulas.html.

Is there a similar formula for the weights of the [*open* Newton-Cotes scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cotes_formulas#Open_Newton.E2.80.93Cotes_formulae)?

Comment: This paper could be of interest : http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/0354-5180/2013/0354-51801304649M.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general expression is
$$
H_{n,k} = \frac{1}{\Psi'(x_k)} \int_a^b \frac{\Psi(x)}{x-x_k}\;\text{d}x
$$
with
$$
\Psi(x) = \prod_{k\in S_n} (x-x_k)
$$
with $S_n$ in the set of quadrature points; see, e.g., http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/0354-5180/2013/0354-51801304649M.pdf (2).

Choosing $a=0, b=n$ and
$$
\text{closed:}\quad S_n = \{k: 0\le k \le n\}\\
\text{open:}\quad S_n = \{k: 1\le k \le n-1\}
$$
makes clear that this is an entirely rational expression. For open Newton-Cotes, it is
$$
H_{n,r}=\frac{(−1)^{n−r+1}}{(r-1)!(n−r-1)!}\int_{0}^n \frac{\prod_1^n(t-k)}{t-r}\;\text{d}t.
$$